# Provision a fleet of Android devices automatically

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to initially setup a fleet of a couple of hundred Android tablets (setting the language, adding account, making settings in Play Store, activating GPS etc.)

What I have right now is an Android test that does various clicks (as a person would do) using uiautomator . It's kind of flaky but it works better than manually doing the setup.

What I want to do is somehow make the Android test as a standalone desktop application so that anyone in the team can provision the devices. But I do not know if it's possible or where to start.

Of course, if there is a better alternative that I haven't thought of, I am all ears.

Comment: Did you ever find something?   I'm looking as well.

Comment: @cph Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found to handle boarding and controlling a ton of devices.

SOTI MobiControl